# Elasticsearch: Operation AND then OR for Query String Function

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsaerch, I am trying to implement operator AND and OR at the same time whereby results with AND is/are **ranked higher** than those of OR.

For example, if I search for "buy fruit". I want the result with:

1. "buy fruit" or "buy...fruit" (order of "buy" and "fruit" doesn't matter) to come up
    first, then follow by
2. "buy" or "fruit" (order of "buy" or "fruit" doesn't matter)

Sorry in advance if someone has already answered this type of issue before. I have been trying to find an answer for this issue but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is the default behaviour of elasticsearch. If more terms match, you get a higher _score.

Comment: Right now, "buy" results or "fruit" results come up before "buy fruit" results. Does this mean the OR results score higher than AND results?

Comment: Are you searching including the quotes? Can you add mapping, put/post of documents and the search query?

Comment: It doesn't include the quotes. The documents are in another language. Please find the search query codes below.